# Checkbox hide/show based on another checkbox value in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using primeng checkbox.Here i want to hide/show and check/unchecked the value based on  condition.

**Condition 1**:

```
If the first checkbox is checked the second and third checkbox will checked and show.
```

**Condition 2:**

```
If the first checkbox is unchecked the second and third checkbox will unchecked and hide.
```

**.html**

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <p-checkbox (onChange)="Changes($event)" 
                label="Documentation" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="isFDV" >
                <p-checkbox  label="doc1" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
            </div> 
            <div *ngIf="isFDV">
                <p-checkbox label="doc2" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
            </div>
         </div>
```

**.ts**

```
 isFDV = false;
    Changes(event) {
       this.isFDV = event;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind with `ngModel` no need to call change event like this -

```
          <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isFDV"  
            label="Documentation" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isFDV" >
            <p-checkbox  label="doc1" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
        </div> 
        <div *ngIf="isFDV">
            <p-checkbox label="doc2" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
        </div>
     </div>
```